# How to check if a week arrangement is part of the month

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, validation, getdate

I would like to be able to validate in an arrangement that brings me the week, if it is part of the month

I pass a start_date to my function, then check if that date is part of a week that starts on Monday and ends on Sunday, so if I pass it today, Monday 5th September 2022, it will return something like this. week :

```
[
  "2022-09-05", // Monday
  "2022-09-06", // Tuesday
  "2022-09-07", // Wednesday
  "2022-09-08", // Thursday
  "2022-09-09", // Friday
  "2022-09-10", // Saturday
  "2022-09-11" // Sunday
]
```

Although that's fine, but I need some validations that so far confuse me a bit, I need to be able to tell my algorithm to validate if the week that it brings is part of the month that is happening, that is, it is missing the date. "2022-09-30", the month is "9", I mean September, so the array is expected to return

```
[
  "2022-09-26",
  "2022-09-27",
  "2022-09-28",
  "2022-09-29",
  "2022-09-30"
]
```

and I would have to return it like this, because that's the last week of the month, so the counter would end there. And then it started again, but validating the following month and so on.

So in the end what I want to return is the week of a month, from Monday to Sunday, validating only the weeks of the month.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
export function ValidateWeek(date_start: any) {
  let curr: Date = date_start;
  const date = new Date(curr);
  let week: any[] = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    let first = date.getDate() - date.getDay() + i;
    let day = new Date(date.setDate(first - 1))
    week.push(day)
  }
  let convertWeek: any = [];
  week.forEach(dateT => {
    const newConvertDate = dateT.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
    convertWeek.push(newConvertDate)
  });
  return convertWeek;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we set our date backwards in time to last monday. Then going forward one by one over a week. Every time date is within same month of input date, we push it to result.

```js
var date_start = "2022-10-01"
var d = new Date(date_start)
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDay();
var offset = day - 1
d.setDate(d.getDate() - offset);
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  if (d.getMonth() === month) {
    result.push(new Date(d.getTime()));
  }
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for answering me, I appreciate it very much, the only thing that I am confused is that in the function that they present to me they pass "2022-10-01" and it returns from September 27 to the date that you passed it, so the objective is that you went back in time? but then it would not be true that I only take the days of the month, because in the end, even if I spend seven days at the counter, I will have to return only the days that are of the month

Comment: Can you better explain or demonstrate the expected result given a date?

Comment: What I try is that if the month starts on a Thursday for example
It will bring me from Thursday to Sunday and then it will normally bring me the weeks something like this: date_start: 09/01/2022 and the result will be["01/09/2022", "02/09/2022", "03/09/2022", "04/09/2022"] and then when you check the next week, it would pass date_start: 09/05/2022 and return["05/09/2022", "06/09 /2022", "07/09/2022", "08/09/2022","09/09/2022", "10/09/2022", "11/09/2022"], and so on until reaching the month that would be week five [" 26/09/2022", "27/09/2022", "28/09/2022", "29/09/2022","30/09/2022"]

Comment: That is already working I think. So what about  2022-10-01 ?

Comment: It should not return it because it is not part of the consulted month, it should only bring the days of the consulted month

Comment: I don't know what is "consulted month" but my solution assumes it is to be the month of the start date (see variable `month`). But you can in your function pass it as parameters instead like `9` or `10`

Comment: Dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD are parsed as UTC, but the function uses local methods. For those with a -ve offset, `new Date('2022-10-01').getMonth()` will return 8, not 9, which might be unexpected.

Comment: How can I remedy that? Would passing time as 12:00PM help?